# Powershell to run exe after vs2010 solution/project build..?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell

I have an exe that I have to run every time I build a project or the entire solution in VS2010. Can I automate this process somehow using Powershell? I've not used Powershell before, but have seen it do a lot of cool things and am hoping that this would be one of those things. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the project properties there is "Build Events" tab and you can set it so the exe will get called after the build process.  MSDN has an article that should help:

[How to: Specify Build Events (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, you just want to use the Build setting. To get PowerShell to run an exe you'd have to use the build event to run PowerShell anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Build events will be fine for you, probably. However, you could look at [StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) - it is PowerShell in VisualStudio that accesses VS internals in a clever way (providers). There are some examples and video that will tell you more.